Are these transactions normal?
When I run this query
SELECT transaction_id, name, transaction_begin_time, transaction_state 
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions

I always have these 6 rows in the result set



transaction_id
name
transaction_begin_time
transaction_state




496
worktable
29/10/2024 00:11:56
2


499
worktable
29/10/2024 00:11:56
2


501
worktable
29/10/2024 00:11:56
2


503
worktable
29/10/2024 00:11:56
2


506
worktable
29/10/2024 00:11:56
2


509
worktable
29/10/2024 00:11:56
2



Is this normal?
And if not, how can I find where they originate from so I can check out what is going on?
Based on the answer from john, I tried this query
SELECT GETDATE() as now,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, transaction_begin_time, GETDATE()) as tran_elapsed_time_seconds,
       st.session_id,
       txt.text,
       at.transaction_id,
       at.transaction_begin_time,
       at.transaction_type,
       at.transaction_status
       
FROM   sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
  left JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st ON st.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON st.session_id = sess.session_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections conn ON conn.session_id = sess.session_id
  OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(conn.most_recent_sql_handle)  AS txt
  
where at.transaction_id in (496, 499, 501, 503, 506, 509)  
  
ORDER BY
   tran_elapsed_time_seconds DESC

and it gives me this result



now
tran_elapsed_time_seconds
session_id
text
transaction_id
transaction_begin_time
transaction_type
transaction_status




26/11/2024 11:01:57
2458201
496


29/10/2024 00:11:56
2
0


26/11/2024 11:01:57
2458201
499


29/10/2024 00:11:56
2
0


26/11/2024 11:01:57
2458201
501


29/10/2024 00:11:56
2
0


26/11/2024 11:01:57
2458201
503


29/10/2024 00:11:56
2
0


26/11/2024 11:01:57
2458201
506


29/10/2024 00:11:56
2
0


26/11/2024 11:01:57
2458201
509


29/10/2024 00:11:56
2
0



When I use an inner join for JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st I get no rows at all.
I don't know how or what more information I can give about this, does the information in this question makes sense to anyone here ?
Edit
I installed WhoIsActive (as proposed in a comment) but it returns no rows while these transactions are the only ones, so I have no help there either

What does sp_WhoIsActive show?

@J.D. I just installed it, it returns no rows at times, so I guess it cannot find who is doing these transactions

Another recent question about these https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/343854/3690

@MartinSmith Thank  you, this pushes me some more in the direction of thinking this is normal behaviour

As per the documentation for sys.dm_tran_active_transactions (Transact-SQL) you might want to run the following statement to determine who is responsible or what might be going on:

 SELECT
   GETDATE() as now,
   DATEDIFF(SECOND, transaction_begin_time, GETDATE()) as tran_elapsed_time_seconds,
   st.session_id,
   txt.text, 
   *
 FROM
   sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st ON st.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON st.session_id = sess.session_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections conn ON conn.session_id = sess.session_id
     OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(conn.most_recent_sql_handle)  AS txt
 ORDER BY
   tran_elapsed_time_seconds DESC;


Without further information your question can probably only be answered with a (well educated) guess.

I updated my question with your query, but it makes no sense to me. What more information can I give you, and how to obtain it ?

You omitted the star from the query. It's hard to find details.

SELECT
   at.transaction_id, 
   at.name,
   at.transaction_begin_time,
   at.transaction_state,
   DB_NAME(db.database_id) AS dbName
FROM
   sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_tran_database_transactions db
    ON at.transaction_id = db.transaction_id
WHERE name = 'worktable'

The query above returns the database where the transactions occur. In this case, the database is tempdb, and these transactions are associated with worktables.
This reference gives us some info about worktable: "Worktables are internal tables that are created in the tempdb database and are not visible to users."
I observed the same six transactions in my system: 
Based on my understanding, these transactions are likely related to internal processes and should not be a significant concern.
Also, I noticed the transaction begin time was closed to when the instance startup:

Thank you, this makes me a bit more relaxed
